# Using make to link multiple .c files into one program?

Tags: c, linker, makefile

I have several .c and custom .h files that I would like to link together using a Makefile, but everything that I've tried has ended up with different results than what I'd like.

Basically, I have the following files : rA.c, rA.h, rB.c, rB.h, rC.c, rC.h, rP.c

What I want would to use a makefile to end up with the equivalent of the following command:
gcc -o rv rA.c rB.c rC.c rP.c

And yield an executable "rv" file. All the ways I've done it so far (which have been hit&miss, admittedly) have yielded intermediate .o files for each .c file but no final rv executable. Any suggestions would be quite appreciated.

Comment: How about posting your makefile? What you are asking for is trivial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILES.o = rA.o rB.o rC.o rP.o
PROGRAM = rv

all: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${FILES.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

You can add dependencies and other bells and whistles as you like, but that's a basic outline of a minimal makefile.

If you are definitively using [GNU `make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), there are shorthand notations to abbreviate the command line more:

```
${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

The first notation shown will work with any version of [`make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) you're likely to lay hands on.

Comment: Works great! I always have huge trouble figuring stuff out when it is described in the most general terms, as many `make` manuals are. Seeing how everything fits and what it does when it is tailored to a specific situation helps me tremendously. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want that resulting command. It doesn't scale well as you add more files.

What you want is a makefile that looks like:

```
rv: rA.o rB.o rC.o rP.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $+
```

This will make `gcc` build each individual `.c` file into an object file, then link all the object files into your executable.

Comment: whoops, missed a bit. try again.

Comment: Edited version works, though I found @JonathanLeffler 's answer more help in understand what I was getting wrong. Thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with a Makefile as simple as:

```
rv: rA.o rB.o rC.o rP.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I'm sorry I can't accept more than one of these answers.